# Как добавить данные в таблице в определенное поле в sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

У меня есть таблица `users_info` и там есть два столбца, в одном из них хранится `id`пользователя а в другом некоторые данные. Как сделать так чтобы по айди пользователя можно было изменять и добавлять некоторые данные. Ну как в словаре например `users_info[id] = data`

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы прочитать или записать\изменить данные в базе данных, нужно сделать запрос.

- Прочитать`select * from имя_таблицы where id=id_пользователя`
- Записать `insert into имя_таблицы (поле) value (значение)`
- Изменить `update имя_таблицы set поле=значение where id=id_пользователя`